# How to add same measure used in different vizualiztions. power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure [expense]. I have two filters filter1(current year expense) and filter2(prev year expense)

I have created two table in a Power Bi report, and used the same measure expense in them both of them such that,

The first table ignores filter 2(prev year expense) and only filter1(current year expense) is applied

The second table ignores filter1 and only filter 2 accepts.

Basically I want to have Current year and prev year expense in two separate tables. This I am able to achieve quite easily, using edit interactions.
But the problem is I also need a third table which should give the result as the total of the two tables. Since I am using the same measure in both the tables, how can I achieve this.

Note:: My total table total summation should change based on filters selected .
Basically table3=table1+table2.

Comment: At least you need to list your measure code.

Comment: measure is simple sum(expense column)

Comment: do you use the date filter? It's hard to advice without understanding of your data set. What do you mean by this - `filter1(current year expense)`?

Comment: Yes just the year filter. I am using the same measure in two separate power bi visuals which is giving separate output based on the filter I select .Now I want to view the same total in a third table visual, how to do that

Comment: What is the field name? What type of data do you use for filter is it a number or dates?

Comment: Field name is Year which is used in filter .It is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Filter the third table with filter1(current year expense). I do not see better solution within your report logic.

```
CALCULATE(
    [expense]
    ,tbl[Year] In {SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[Year]),SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[Year])-1}
)
```

Comment: This is not working becasue, there are two selected values for tbl[Year] , I am using them in both filters. one has prev year lets say 2021 and one has current year 2022, so it is not returning any result

Comment: You have no other option. This will work if you filter the measure with only  one filter `filter1(current year expense)`. The second filter you need to adjust not to influence the matrix.